# Failing to convert column in pandas dataframe to integer data type

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code which manipulates a data set to create a new column by pulling info from an existing column. In order to match the data properly using a pd.merge function with another data set, I would like to convert the 'Channel ID' column to integers. Despite the current use of .astype(int) the results data type shows up as float64 looking at frame with .info()

```
def cost(received_frame):
    received_frame.columns = ['Campaign', 'Ad Spend']
    campaigns = received_frame['Campaign']
    ID = []
    for c in campaigns:
        blocks = re.split('_', c)
        for block in blocks[1:]:
            if len(block) == 6 and block.isdigit(): 
                ID.append(block)
    ID = pd.Series(ID).str.replace("'","")
    ID = pd.DataFrame(ID)
    both = [ID,received_frame]
    frame = pd.concat(both,axis=1)
    frame.columns = ['Channel ID', 'Campaign', 'Ad Spend']
    frame['Channel ID'] = frame['Channel ID'].dropna().astype(int)
    return frame
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the data you are working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
frame['Channel ID'].dropna().astype(int)
```

You're returning a series with possibly fewer indices, as you're dropping NAs.

Then, when you assign it as

```
frame['Channel ID'] = frame['Channel ID'].dropna().astype(int)
```

It performs a sort of merge with the existing values (according to the indices), and those are floats, so it must convert these too.

You should replace it with something else, depending on your problem (`fillna`?).

Comment: That got it! thank you but I still can't merge the dataframes correctly :(

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51417159/2901002) problem and if possible, create answer? I think there are necessary some graph or networkx and it is too hard for me. If solution will be created, I really like upvote it ;) Only plese let me know it ;) Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael Hi! My apologies, but I just don't have time at the moment (work). Thanks for the note, though!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `frame` looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.DataFrame({'Channel ID':['1',np.nan,'2'], 'foo':['bar','baz',np.nan]})
```

---

```
  Channel ID  foo
0          1  bar
1        NaN  baz
2          2  NaN
```

---

You could drop rows from `frame` where `Channel ID` is NaN:

```
mask = pd.notnull(frame['Channel ID'])
frame = frame.loc[mask]
```

and then `astype(int)` will successful convert the column to dtype `int`:

```
frame['Channel ID'] = frame['Channel ID'].astype(int)
```

yields

```
   Channel ID  foo
0           1  bar
2           2  NaN
```

---

As Ami Tavory explained, you can't drop the NaNs *solely* from `frame['Channel ID']` 
with

```
frame['Channel ID'] = frame['Channel ID'].dropna()
```

because upon assignment *aligns* the index on the right-hand side with  the
relevant rows on the left-hand side. It has no effect on the rows on the left whose index is not mentioned on the right-hand side. So the NaNs remain in the bigger DataFrame,
`frame`.

Since NaN is a float value, the dtype must remain a float dtype as long as the column contains NaNs.